# Imprimir un arrayList que guarda cadenas de un archivo .csv

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

Estoy haciendo un recorrido de un archivo .csv y lo guardo en un array para el idcase y otro para activity, y después lo imprimo, y al momento de imprimirlo me imprime cada iteración de cada actividad como lo muestro en lo siguiente:

```js
1[register request]
1[register request, examine thoroughly]
1[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket]
1[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide]
1[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request]
2[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request]
2[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket]
2[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually]
2[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide]
2[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation]
3[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request]
3[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually]
3[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket]
3[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide]
3[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request]
3[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly]
3[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket]
3[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide]
3[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation]
4[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request]
4[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket]
4[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly]
4[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide]
4[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request]
5[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request, register request]
5[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually]
5[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually, check ticket]
5[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide]
5[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request]
5[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, check ticket]
5[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, check ticket, examine casually]
5[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, check ticket, examine casually, decide]
5[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, reinitiate request]
5[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, reinitiate request, examine casually]
5[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, reinitiate request, examine casually, check ticket]
5[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, reinitiate request, examine casually, check ticket, decide]
5[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, reinitiate request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reject request]
6[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, reinitiate request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request]
6[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, reinitiate request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually]
6[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, reinitiate request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually, check ticket]
6[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, reinitiate request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide]
6[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation, register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, reinitiate request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reject request, register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, pay compensation]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Y lo que quiero que muestre es solo la ultima fila de cada idcase, osea así:

```js
1[register request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, reject request]
2[register request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, pay compensation]
3[register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, examine thoroughly, check ticket, decide, pay compensation]
4[register request, check ticket, examine thoroughly, decide, reject request]
5[register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reinitiate request, check ticket, examine casually, decide, reinitiate request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, reject request]
6[register request, examine casually, check ticket, decide, pay compensation]
```

Me podrían explicar u orientar a como lograr que me lo imprima así, en que parte de mi código debiera cambiar.
La manera en que los voy iterando es con 2 ciclos for, la función ,equals la ocupo para comparar las actividades en otros pasos mas adelante

```js
 public static final char SEPARATOR=';';
  public static final char QUOTE='"';
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
CSVReader reader = null;

try {
             
  reader = new CSVReader(new            FileReader("example.csv"),SEPARATOR,QUOTE);
 String[] nextLine=null;

ArrayList idcase = new ArrayList();
ArrayList activity = new ArrayList();
ArrayList letra = new ArrayList();
  
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
     
             activity.add(nextLine[3]);
              idcase.add(nextLine[0]);
              
              }
```

```
 for (int x=0; x < activity.size(); x++) {
   System.out.print(idcase.get(x));
for (int y=0; y < activity.size() ; y++) {
    if (activity.get(x).equals(activity.get(y))){

     letra.add(activity.get(x));

     System.out.println(letra);

     break;
```

```js
}
       catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      } finally {
         if (null != reader) {
            reader.close();
         } 
      }
```

Comment: Me parece que omitiste parte del código.

Comment: ya lo actualice @E.Betanzos

Answer (score 0):

En tus ciclos deberias de indicar con un condicional if que si el idcase es el ultimo entonces debe de imprimirlo, ejemplo.

Suponiendo que tengo una serie de frases:

```
id[][] = {[1, Hola, serie],
          [1, Hola, serie],
          [1, Hola, serie],
          [2, Hola, serie],
          [2, Hola, serie]};

acumulador_inicial = id[0][0]

for(int i = 1; i < id.length; i++;){
   acumulador_iterativo = id[i][0];
   if(id_inicial != id_iterativo){
      id_inicial = id_iterativo;
      System.out.println(id); //Aqui tu agregarias el for correspondiente de la 
                              //impresion.
   }
}
```

Ahora solo debes de hacer algo similar de acuerdo a tu codigo porque por lo que veo te falto agregar algunas partes del mismo y no entiendo por completo tu estructura.

Practicamente lo que estoy queriendote decir con esto es que te asegures de que hagas una condicional para que tu programa solo tome tu ultimo idcase de acuerdo a tu numeracion que es sencillo ya que es solamente una acumulacion de datos y comparacion.

Comment: Gracias lo voy a adaptar para mi código para ver si me funciona, y ya actualice @ASASCED